# Giving spark thrift server the path to warehouse directory

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, tableau-api, spark-thriftserver

I have setup my spark cluster and I am successful in connecting Tableau through Spark SQL connector.

I created my tables from spark shell and saved dataframes from MySQL using (`saveAsTable`).

How can I access the tables that I have saved from Tableau? Do I need to give a path of the warehouse directory when starting the spark thrift server? If yes, how it can be done and if no, how can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

> Make sure you are pointing to the **same metastore for *spark-shell* and
>   *thriftserver***
>
> Metastore sharing can be 2 ways, in simple
>
> 1. Starting both shell and thrift from same location
> 2. Setting up remote database for metastore

You can pass hive confs to Spark thrift server with `--hiveconf` and Spark confs with `--conf`

```
./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh \
  --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=path/to/warehouse/dir \
  --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=<listening-port> \
  --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host=<listening-host> \
  --master <master-uri>
  ...
```